# Passing JSON file as a parameter to the downstream job

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two jobs:

A- This runs a python script and generates a JSON file.

B- This runs a set of smoke test suites using a script. This script requires the above created JSON file as a parameter to execute it.

Both of the above jobs are in separate folders in the GIT repo.

Is there a way I can pass the JSON file created from Job A to Job B.

Note: I do not want to use custom workspace here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job A can archive the json file as. 
Job B can download this file ( you can download latest or use another parameter for Job A build number) and continue with your flow.

Thanks , Mor

Answer (score 0):

If you archive the file in Job A, then use the *copy artifact plugin* to pull that file into job B.

Even better, combine the jobs into a single pipeline and then you can stash and unstash the files you need.